# Am I correctly inserting objects into heap

Tags: java, generics, heap, comparable

I am learning to use generics and have had some issues with how my objects are being compared. I have created a `generic` heap class so it can accept any comparable object. My question is if I am adding objects and using `generics` correctly so that I can accept any type of comparable object. Specifically, I am not sure if i am adding objects correctly in my `addNode()` method.

```
public class Heap<T extends Comparable<T>> {
private ArrayList<T> heap;
public Heap(){
    heap = new ArrayList<T>();
}
public int getSize(){
    return heap.size();
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return heap.isEmpty();
}
public int getPLoc(int i){
    return (i - 1) / 2;
}
public int getLCLoc(int i){
    return 2 * i + 1;
}
public int getRCLoc(int i){
    return 2 * i + 2;
}
public T getNodeAt(int i) {
    if(heap.get(i) == null) {
        System.out.println("Item does not exist.");
        return null;
    }else {
        return heap.get(i);
    }
}
public void addNode(T n) {
    heap.add(null);
    int index = heap.size() - 1;
    while(index > 0 && (getNodeAt(getPLoc(index)).compareTo(n) < 0)) { // Is this correct?
        heap.set(index, getNodeAt(getPLoc(index)));
        index = getPLoc(index);
    }
    heap.set(index, n);
}
```

Comment: override `compareTo`, extend `Comparable` interface

Comment: Looks fine. Do you have a reason why you are asking this? It all seems hypothetical.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I was asking because I was not sure if this was the source of an error I was having where my objects are not being compared correctly. But, that's a different question.